# Plone Container modification date of contained objects for hash/cache value

Tags: python, plone, zope

In Plone, the ModificationDate and effective date of container objects really returns the last time the container was modified, but doesn't keep track of the contained object's modification times.

I'm wondering if there is **a better way, or even some simple built-in way** alternative to this awkward and potentially very slow query to determine the date that a container's contents were modified - or in this case below - the last time something was 'added'.

```
def getFolderModificationDate(folderBrain, catalog):
    """Returns last time content was modified inside a folder"""

    brains = catalog.search(query_request={ "path": folderBrain.getPath(),
                                            "portal_type": 'Article',
                                            'review_state':'published'},
                            sort_index = 'effective',
                            reverse=1,
                            limit=1)

    if brains:
        return brains[0].ModificationDate
    else:
        #return the folder's modificationDate
        return folderBrain.ModificationDate
```

This date will be used downstream in a non-plone application as a hash value for caching the folder's contents.

Comment: Nope, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: I agree with Martijn. There's no particular reason why that query would be slow. The catalog is very good at that kind of chore.

Comment: Maybe if only additions, deletions, renames, and reorders constitute a container modification (but not edits/updates of contained objects), you should use respective event subscribers for the container/contained (IObjectAddedEvent, IObjectMovedEvent, IContainerModifiedEvent) to simply set an indexed attribute on the folder?  This seems more precise, and might be about the same amount of work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Answer the question with 'That's how I'd do it' and I'll accept it. #cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's exactly how I'd do it.

The alternative would be to use an event to update the modification date of parent folders, but that'd incur a the risk of conflict errors.